# A little issue with the app resolution

Tags: cordova

First, sorry for my bad english. So, i've a problem with the resolution of my aplication. I'm working with pixel art so, I need my app preserve the original resolution of all images, i don't know if you understand me, but, here's a couple images:

It looks like this: [The app looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYTLF.jpg)

The original image looks like this: [The image looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FlMG.png)

The code is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,
width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src='design/img/avatar.png' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Is a simple document (still yet) because i need to solve the problem for continue with my project.

Uh, i'm practicately new in the world of hybrid apps. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your image a set width/height in a stylesheet like so

```
.classname{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

If you find these are being overruled then you can use the !important flag like so:

```
.classname{
    width:100px!important;
    height:100px!important;
}
```

This should then always retain the image size asper the styles.

Comment: Really, I have a sample app using your image and if i specify a fixed width and height for the image, it applies it. Can you post the css for the image? I assume you gave your image a class and then referred the css to that class?

Comment: Try using this as your image code    <img src="design/img/avatar.png" style="width:106px!important; height:108px!important;" /> or whatever pixel size you need

Comment: I did exactly that (put the css in style attribute), and still looks weird.

Comment: Try changing your viewport to <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, but still the same. The code goes like this: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <img src='design/img/avatar.png' style='width:106px;height:108px;' />
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Add the !important tags to width and height like so width:106px!important;height:108px!important;

Comment: With or Without !important, the same. The image doesn't look like pixel art. Looks a little blured

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Answer Update**

You are getting blurred image into your application is just because of your png image and white application background.

try adding background color red you will get original image as you expected, I just want you to know that image is showing blur because of png image and background combinations, either you have to change image border or background of image container

```
body{
    background-color: red;
}
```